# When is $P_\mathcal S ACA'Q_\mathcal S = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

All matrices in this question are real. Let C be a positive definite matrix and $A$ an arbitrary square matrix such that the product $ACA'$ makes sense. Let $\mathcal S$ be a space such that $R(A')\subseteq \mathcal S$, where $R$ here stands for range, or the column space of its matrix argument. The associated orthogonal projections are denoted $P_\mathcal S, Q_\mathcal S := I - P_\mathcal S$.

What are necessary conditions on $\mathcal S$ for $P_\mathcal S ACA'Q_\mathcal S = 0$ to hold always? An obvious sufficient condition is that $R(A) \subseteq \mathcal S$ since then $(A'Q_\mathcal S)' = Q_\mathcal S A=0$. My intuition tells me that it is also necessary, but I cannot prove it.

As pointed out in the comments, $A'$ means the transpose of $A$.

**Edit:** We may assume $P_\mathcal S C Q_\mathcal S = 0$.

Comment: FYI, to people who don't understand the use of $\prime$, it is just the same as the matrix transpose.

Comment: Thanks @Clarinetist, added clarification.